# Rules of typography on starting new paragraphs

Tags: typography

A bit of an embarrassing question, but I still hope I get an understandable answer:

When should a paragraph indent (by that I mean a new paragraph) be started? In my editor, I just use a blank line or `\par`. I wrote a somewhat longer text and I have the feeling that I have added quite a few new paragraphs without knowing whether this is the right thing to do.

For example: Is it typographically okay if I add `\\` after a colon or should I have used a paragraph indent (just see my MWE)? Or neither?

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

We want to dedicate ourselves to a small, spontaneous example:\\Should there be a paragraph indent, or not?

\end{document}
```

vs.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

We want to dedicate ourselves to a small, spontaneous example:\par Should there be a paragraph indent, or not?

\end{document}
```

vs.

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}

\begin{document}

\section{Example}

We want to dedicate ourselves to a small, spontaneous example: Should there be a paragraph indent, or not?

\end{document}
```

Comment: I see no reason for a line break after a colon unless you're starting a list.  Resist the urge of breaking lines mid-paragraph and your documents will be prettier and better readable.

Comment: a colon does not end the sentence so the usual form would be to follow with a space and do not capitalise the following word. If the following text is a display list do not put a blank line before the list then latex will not indent the text after the list but set it as a continuation of the current paragraph.

Comment: @egreg My problem is that I often start new paragraphs in my documents. Sometimes the paragraphs are only a sentence long ...

Comment: I think your query is overwhelmingly about grammar and general typography, and only peripherally about TeX and LaTeX. As such, please consider moving your query to either [English language & usage](https://english.stackexchange.com/) or [English language learners](https://ell.stackexchange.com/) -- or to whatever language site that's relevant for your document.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You should never use `\par` in a document (use a blank line) and almost never use `\\` outside of alignments such as `align` or `tabular`.
I would also recommend in your TeX source to have lines a reasonable length, your editor may "soft wrap" but other tools (for example this site) the long lines are a lot less convenient.

The rest of your question isn't really on topic as it's a matter of Grammar not TeX markup. In British English a colon doesn't end a sentence, so should be followed by a space and the following word is not captialised, although apparently American English does prefer to capitalise here:
http://www.sussex.ac.uk/informatics/punctuation/colonandsemi/colon .

If what follows is a list, do not use a blank line before the list, LaTeX will then set the following text as part of the same paragraph.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}
Some text about something. Some text about something. Some text about something. 
Some text about something. Some text about something. Some text about something. 
This is a mid sentence displayed list:
\begin{enumerate}
\item red;
\item blue;
\item green;
\end{enumerate}
and the sentence ends here.

But  the following list is a complete paragraph.

\begin{enumerate}
\item Red;
\item blue;
\item green.
\end{enumerate}

This following text is therefore a new paragraph.

\end{document}
```

Comment: It figures the Brits (University of Sussex) would *think* that Americans prefer to capitalize after a colon. Sheesh!  No wonder why 1776 seemed inevitable, in retrospect.   "Yes, your royal Majuscule"

Answer (score 7):

The command `\par` or the blank line, like many others like `\section{}` or `\tile{}`  have a semantic meaning, not a typographical (formatting) meaning. In this case, `\par` mean the end of a paragraph, that is a group of sentences about the same idea, and  therefore, the next text should be formatted accordingly, but not necessarily always in the same way. It could be a line break plus indentation or/and a vertical skip, with less o more indentation and/or less o more vertical skip indentation. On the contrary, the `\\` have not any semantic meaning,  is just a formatting order, that only make a line break, and  **it does not end the paragraph**, and always produce the same typographical effect, while `\par` can produce different effects depending on the document settings.

In other words, after a colon, is fine a `\par` (if there is a change of topic) or nothing, (the next words are part of the sentence, or a new sentence but about the same topic), but never a `\\`.

**Rule of thumb**: If you are using  `\\` but it is not the end of a row in a `tabular`-like environment, probably you are doing something wrong.